# Where does Spotify Beta install?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, facebook, spotify

I used both locate & whereis to locate post apt-get install proc specd by Facebook, but cant the locate the helper app for firefox to use.... natty narwhal 11.04

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg -L package_name` will list the files installed by a package.